# Unable to create client VM that access Azure Sql Managed Instance due to core quota limit

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have create Azure SQL Managed Instance and I want to create client VM that will be used to access the instance. I have copied the configuration script from the Azure portal:

[image]

When I execute this script via PowerShell, I'm getting the following error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:06:13 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'azuredeploy' is not valid according to the 
>   validation procedure. The tracking id is '8bc76e8d-3070-44a3-bc43-58bbeeac20d8'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
>   At line:179 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupN ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
>
> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:06:14 PM - Error: Code=QuotaExceeded; Message=Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 100, Current 
>   in use: 100, Additional requested: 2. Please read more about quota increase at http://aka.ms/corequotaincrease.
>   At line:179 char:1
>   + New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupN ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

If these some explanation why this error happens and hot to see what is the current quota?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error shows that you have InvalidTemplateDeployment. You could execute this script with [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) here to run commands on local and remote computers. Once you copy this script to your power shell command line, you would need to set the password for VM and execute the script. Once you execute the script, you will see that it deployed your VM. You can get more details from this [step by step](https://argonsys.com/learn-microsoft-cloud/library/the-easiest-way-to-create-azure-vm-that-can-access-your-azure-sql-managed-instance/).

For the second error. The quota is for each individual region, not for the entire subscription. You can use the `Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location "South Central US"` command to find virtual machine quotas with a specific location. You can get more reference about [resolving errors for resource quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quota-errors).